# How to access to element _product by using PHP 7.0

Tags: php, prestashop

Maybe this is simple but I have problem with this. How to access to element _products. This is Prestashop 1.6

```
 public function hookActionOrderStatusUpdate($params) {
        $a = $params['cart'];
    }
```

[image]

This is output of $a

```
Cart Object ( 
[_products:protected] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [category] => plany
```

Comment: you need to print the array `echo'<pre>';print_r($a);echo'</pre>';` then you will see its structure.

Comment: try $a->_products?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't access a protected or private property directly, you need to find a publicly exposed method on the class. In [Prestashop's `Cart` class](https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop/blob/1.6.1.x/classes/Cart.php#L484), the relevant method is `getProducts`:

```
public function hookActionOrderStatusUpdate($params) {
    $products = $params['cart']->getProducts();
}
```